# API call in lazy-load function, limiting the api response

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I've set up a project where Im limiting the API response to 5, and upon scrolling to the bottom o the page, I make a new API call to fetch the next 2 items in the API. But with the current code it only checks if the 5 items previously fetched exists in the cards state. Im quite unsure as to how to go about fetching the 2 next items in the API? Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about this? Thanks,

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    cards: []
},
methods: {
    scroll(card) {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + 
            window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            if(bottomOfWindow) {
            const url = 
            'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cab36508b8d1301a25bd8fa/1/';
                axios.get(url)
               .then(response => {
               for (var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
                            console.log('Cards id: ', this.cards[i].id)
                            if(this.cards[i].id !== 
                            response.data.results[i].id){            
                                for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {   
                                this.cards.push(response.data.results[x])
                                }

                            } else{
                                console.log('No more cards to load')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    },
    getAPI(){
        const url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cab36508b8d1301a25bd8fa/1/';


            axios.get(url)

            .then(response => {
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    this.cards.push(response.data.results[i]);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
        console.log(this.cards)

    }
},
mounted() {
    this.scroll(this.card)
}
})
```

Comment: This loop of yours inside the `.then` is just a pseudocode of the real limited API? Like, you are not really limiting the response in this example.

Comment: I do limit the initial response in another segment of code. I edited the code. Would this be a more appropriate way to about it? Thanks.

Comment: Can we get a working example in JSFiddle?

Comment: @Deckerz Certainly, https://jsfiddle.net/leetajz/4rbwkj6a/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the method in which you do the checking. Instead of doing it from cards length you loop through the results length and once you reach a card that doesnt exist you add them, keep track of the amount added and return after 2 or when there is none left. I changed the loop logic to so.

```
//Card with position i from results doesn't exist
if(this.cards[i] == undefined){
   //add this card - maybe add more logic to check for duplicate incase of reordering of response
   this.cards.push(response.data.results[i])
   //track card added
   cardsAdded++;
} else {
    console.log('No more cards to load')
}

//check if cards added has reach limit of 2
if(cardsAdded == 2)
    return;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/as4dm03q/